# command not found, while it exist in appropriate place

Tags: command, keyboard-layout, command-not-found, rc.local

i had fresh installed debian 12 and almost all commands are not found.

```
root@debian:/# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
bash: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found
```

i find it here

```
root@debian:/home/lm# find /usr -type f -name debconf
/usr/bin/debconf
/usr/lib/tasksel/tests/debconf
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/debconf
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/debconf
```

as it still not found i even reinstall it

```
root@debian:/home/lm# apt-get install dpkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
dpkg is already the newest version (1.21.22
```

but it still not found

```
root@debian:/home/lm# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
bash: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found
root@debian:/home/lm# apt-get install debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
debconf is already the newest version (1.5.82).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

even after this it still not found, and PATH is looks like this

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
```

so, i don't know, how to reconfigure my keyboard now?

```
Linux debian 6.1.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.38-2 (2023-07-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You're looking for `dpkg-reconfigure`, but you ask `find` for `debconf`; that makes no sense.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure` is in package `debconf` ... so, the fact that you have `debconf` suggests you should have `dpkg-reconfigure` - what's the output of `command -v dpkg-reconfigure`

Comment: ```root@debian:~# -v dpkg-reconfigure
-bash: -v: command not found```